# Convert greyscale JPEG to rgb JPEG, retaining quality

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have a few JPEG files containing images in grayscale.  I wish to convert these images to RGB (i.e. three channels) and save them as new JPEG files and with the same (or almost the same) quality as the original images.  I wish to use the Python Pillow package.

I tried the following steps, but it does not retain the quality of the original image:

```sh
$ jhead gray.JPEG
File name    : gray.JPEG
File size    : 68741 bytes
File date    : 2021:10:25 04:54:30
Resolution   : 500 x 333
Color/bw     : Black and white
JPEG Quality : 96
```

```py
gray = PIL.Image.open("gray.JPEG")
rgb = gray.convert(mode="RGB")
rgb.save("rgb.JPEG")
```

```sh
$ jhead rgb.JPEG
File name    : rgb.JPEG
File size    : 25622 bytes
File date    : 2021:10:25 05:04:20
Resolution   : 500 x 333
JPEG Quality : 75
```

How can I do the conversion using PIL.Image and retain the quality of the JPEG image?

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Answer**

Assuming you are focussed on getting the job done, rather than having a specifically PIL/Pillow-based answer like below, you can do what you want with **ImageMagick** without writing any code just in Terminal as follows. Make a **copy** of your files first and work in a separate directory as `mogrify` is a VERY powerful command:

```
magick mogrify -colorspace srgb -type truecolor *.jpg
```

If you want to avoid overwriting your original files, specify a path for output files:

```
mkdir OUTPUT
magick mogrify -path OUTPUT -colorspace srgb -type truecolor *.jpg
```

This should retain the dpi, quality and other metadata too. If you like these results but really insist on Python, I am pretty certain you can do the above in Python with [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) which is derived from **ImageMagick**.

**Original Answer**

This seems to be the topic of some [discussion](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/857) and confusion. Basically, the quality is not actually directly embedded in a JPEG. I think the safest bet for the moment is to extract the quality of the original and write using the same value, something like this:

```
import subprocess
from PIL import Image

# Load input image and convert to RGB
filename = 'input.jpg'
im = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')

# Get quality estimate of original using "exiftool"
proc = subprocess.run(["exiftool","-s3","-JPEGQualityEstimate",filename], capture_output=True)
q=int(proc.stdout)
print(f'File: {filename}, estimated quality: {q}')

# Save with that quality
im.save('result.jpg', quality=q)
```

For production quality, you should check result and handle errors/exceptions and so on.

---

If you don't have `exiftool` installed, you could use this command with **ImageMagick** to extract the quality:

```
magick input.jpg -format %Q info:
```

---

If you want to stick with `jhead`, you could use something like:

```
import re

# Guesstimate quality using "jhead"
proc = subprocess.run(["jhead",filename], capture_output=True)
it = re.search(r'JPEG Quality\s*:\s*(\d+)', str(proc.stdout))
q = int(it.group(1))
```

Comment: Mark, thank you for your response.  Basically, run an external process to get the JPEG quality number and use that in the im.save() method, right?

I wish there was a simpler way to do the conversion in Pillow itself.  Barring that, I wish there was a way to compute JPEG quality (just as the exiftool or imagemagick or jhead does).  After all, the conversion involves repetition of a HxW or HxWx1 array into a HxWx3 array and everything else about the image remains the same.

Comment: There is an option to provide your own qtables to `im.save()` if you feel like pursuing that... https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg

Comment: I gave this method a shot as well -- specified both the qtables and the subsampling.  It does not retain the dpi and jfif info though.

Comment: I have updated my answer above.